# How to calculate total balance in sql using sum?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

updated question --

I have a table that contains the following columns:

```
DROP TABLE TABLE_1;
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1(
TRANSACTION_ID number, USER_KEY number,AMOUNT number,CREATED_DATE DATE, UPDATE_DATE DATE
);

insert into TABLE_1
values ('001','1001',75,'2022-12-02','2022-12-03'),
('001','1001',-74.98,'2022-12-02','2022-12-03'),
('001','1001',74.98,'2022-12-03','2022-12-04'),
('001','1001',-75,'2022-12-03','2022-12-04')
```

I need to calculate the balance based on the update date. In some cases there can be the same update_date for two different records. When I have this, I want to grab the lower value of the balance.

This is the query I have so far:

```
select * from (
select TRANSACTION_ID,USER_KEY,AMOUNT,CREATED_DATE,UPDATE_DATE,
sum(AMOUNT) over(partition by USER_KEY order by UPDATE_DATE rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as TOTAL_BALANCE_AMOUNT
from TABLE_1
) qualify row_number() over (partition by USER_KEY order by UPDATE_DATE DESC, UPDATE_DATE DESC) = 1
```

In the query above, it's is grabbing the 75, rather than the 0 after I try to only grab the LAST balance.

Is there a way to include in the qualify query to grab the last balance but if the dates are the same, to grab the lowest balance?

Comment: What is the account_key column? The sample does not contain such column. Second DATE is not deterministic(two dates are the same per the same user_key, which one should be treated as first and why?

Comment: Aside from the non-deterministic sort, this will produce a final row of 0. I just tested it sorting both ASC and DESC with the amounts added to the sort. The intermediate balances will be different that way, but the final will be 0 . Can you share your output table?

Comment: There seems to be some detail missing from the question.  Do you mean total sum by transaction date or by user_key?  Simplified version is "select USER_KEY,  sum(AMOUNT) from table1 group by USER_KEY"  That gives you 0.

Comment: Hello! I am trying to find the balance of all the transaction, each day a new record will get added, so order by date, I need to calculate the balance of the amount. In the example above, (75-75) on Dec.2, then (0+75) then (75-75)

Comment: So you need to aggregate to the day and then run the running sum in the window function. CTE or subquery will work here.

Comment: I added more to the question

Comment: why is the second query, showing 4 different record balances?

Comment: You need to have additional criteria for sorting.  Otherwise you will not get consistent results if you can have multiple rows for the same id and date.

Comment: Honesty, I'm confused about how that output isn't exactly what you describe? Can you please share both sample data AND desired results from that sample data? Your explanation and showing of wrong results isn't clear.

Comment: Hello ,I reworded the question! I need to to be able to grab the last balance record and if the dates are the sam, it should grab the lowest balance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is the second query, showing 4 different record balances?

That is the point of "running total". If the goal is to have a single value per entire window then order by should be skipped:

```
select USER_KEY, 
       sum(AMOUNT) over(partition by USER_KEY) as TOTAL_BALANCE_AMOUNT
from TABLE1;
```

The partition by clause could be futher expanded with date to produce output per user_key/date:

```
select USER_KEY, 
       sum(AMOUNT) over(partition by USER_KEY,date) as TOTAL_BALANCE_AMOUNT
from TABLE1;
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer! I reworded the question though! I need to to be able to grab the last balance record and if the dates are the sam, it should grab the lowest balance).

Comment: so when the dates are the same, it should calculate the balance based on the positive value first

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this, aggregate by USER_ID, DATE, and then calculate a running sum. If this is not what you're looking for nor is Lukasz Szozda's answer, please edit the question to show the intended output.

```
    create or replace table T1(USER_KEY int, AMOUNT number(38,2), "DATE" date);
    
    insert into T1(USER_KEY, AMOUNT, "DATE") values
    (1001, 75,  '2022-12-02'),
    (1001, -75, '2022-12-02'),
    (1001, 75,  '2022-12-03'),
    (1001, -75, '2022-12-03');
    
-- Option 1, aggregate after window
select USER_KEY, "DATE", min(TOTAL_BALANCE_AMOUNT) as MINIMUM_BALANCE from 
(
select USER_KEY, "DATE", sum(AMOUNT)
over(partition by USER_KEY order by DATE, AMOUNT desc rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as TOTAL_BALANCE_AMOUNT from
T1
)
group by USER_KEY, "DATE"
;

--Option 2, qualify by partitioning by user and day, reversing the order of transactions
select USER_KEY, "DATE", sum(AMOUNT)
over(partition by USER_KEY order by DATE, AMOUNT desc rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as TOTAL_BALANCE_AMOUNT
from
T1
qualify row_number() over (partition by USER_KEY, DATE order by DATE, AMOUNT asc) = 1
;
```

| USER_KEY | DATE | TOTAL_BALANCE_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022-12-02 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 1001 | 2022-12-03 00:00:00 | 0 |

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer! A I reworded the question though! I need to to be able to grab the last balance record and if the dates are the sam, it should grab the lowest balance).

Comment: There's still the question of how you calculate a balance on a single day. Do you credit all the positive transactions first or the negative transactions first? How do you handle ties? It makes a big difference when calculating the lowest balance. In other words, there is no "last balance" for a day unless the order of the transactions is deterministic.

Comment: It should be positive first when there are ties

Comment: Okay. You can aggregate after the window or use qualify ordering the transactions in the reverse order they're applied and grab the first one.